# Lyx - Saving error when using Russian letters in filename

Tags: errors, lyx

I can't find a reason why the file is not saved if the name has Russian characters.

[image]

Rename doesn't help.

OS: Windows 10 x64.

Installed and tried lyx versions from 2.3.0 until the new one. x32, x64 - both versions tried. Tried to install it on different disc spaces (C:, D:, E:). Changed localization and language settings of Windows. Clearly have no idea why it's not working now. And Lyx is the only app that not work.

upd. 2.1.5 version same error...

Thank you for reading. And sorry for my bad English.

Comment: lyx has a bug tracker: https://www.lyx.org/trac/wiki/BugTrackerHome

Comment: I would not try to hard and just avoid the problematic letters. Same issue in German :).

Comment: Dr. Manuel Kuehner, atm i am doing so. But I have hundreds of Lyx files and I need to share them with people we work together with. It will be painful to change all names to eng letters and when I share rechange them to exact that name, my team uses.

Answer (score 2):

Holy moly! It was hard to find out. Here is a possible solution (worked for me):

Control panel => Clock and Region => Region => Administrative => Change system locale... And set what you need (I guess). After that restart PC.

Here is a pic:[image]

P.S. Possibly this will fix problems with any other languages too. But I am not sure about it.